# Ansible: enforce pipefail

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, pipe, ansible

Earlier today, we experienced a nasty issue that was caused by the following shell pipe:

```
- name: get remote branches
  shell: git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:orga/repo.git | sed 's_.*refs/heads/__g'
  register: branches_remote
```

The `git` command fails, but the return code of the entire pipe is 0. [This is default bash/sh behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1550933/353337).

To fix this, in sh/bash, you can `set -o pipefail` or `set -e`. Is it possible to do that in ansible, preferably globally for all my `shell` commands?

Comment: does ansible's [git module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html) not work for you?

Comment: We need to extract a remote branch name, manipulate it a little bit, and store it in a variable. If this can be done without `shell`, that'd be great of course.

Comment: `set -e` is not a substitute for `set -o pipefail` (contrary to what the "or" in the question implies); if you want your script to pass through the first failed exit status from any failed pipeline component without proceeding to later commands, you need *both*.

Comment: ...that said, `shell:` uses `/bin/sh` by default, for which `set -o pipefail` isn't guaranteed to be available at all.

Comment: You *could* implement this as a local patch to `library/commands/command`, but... eww.

Answer (score 4):

In general you should try to use the shell commands as a last resort as they tend to be a bit brittle. If you need to use the shell module with any shell options, simply submit it as part of your command pipeline as shown below. The executable parameter forces the use of bash shell.

```
[user@ansible ~]$ ansible myhost -m shell -a "executable=/bin/bash set -o pipefail && false | echo hello there"
myhost | FAILED | rc=1 >>
hello there

[user@ansible ~]$ ansible myhost -m shell -a "executable=/bin/bash set -o pipefail && true | echo hello there"
myhost | success | rc=0 >>
hello there
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash accepts `set -o pipefail`, but the default executable is `/bin/sh` which, on platforms such as Debian, is not guaranteed to support this, probably for a good reason (dash is a pure-posix shell).

You can configure `/bin/bash` as the executable in **ansible.cfg**:

```
[defaults]
executable = /bin/bash
```

The same can be done in **molecule.yml**

```yaml
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  config_options:
    defaults:
      executable: /bin/bash
```

There is no configuration `executable_flags` available, so you should adjust the actions yourself:

```yaml
- name: pipes that fail should fail the action
  shell: |
    set -e -o pipefail
    git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:orga/repo.git | sed 's_.*refs/heads/__g'
   register: branches_remote
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* set the executable for the shell module, for example:

```yaml
- name: get remote branches
  shell: |
    set -e -o pipefail
    git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:orga/repo.git | sed 's_.*refs/heads/__g'
   args:
     executable: /usr/bin/bash
   register: branches_remote
```